# What is the Xamarin equivalent of kCLHeadingFilterNone?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In order to use [CLLocationManager.HeadingFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620550-headingfilter) I want to use [kCLHeadingFilterNone](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/kclheadingfilternone) as mentioned in the first link. However, I can't seem to find it in Xamarin. (I've tried `CLLocationManager`'s properties and similar things but to no avail.)

So how do I set `HeadingFilter` to `kCLHeadingFilterNone` in Xamarin?

Comment: `CLLocationDistance.FilterNone`?

Comment: HeadingFilter is a `double`, just assign it `0` (`kCLHeadingFilterNone` is just a const in ObjC assigned to zero)

Comment: @SushiHangover How do you know it's zero? [And how do we know it won't be changed? I'm assuming that's why Apple doesn't tell us what it is, so we'll use that field instead of hard coding a value?]

Comment: @orhtej2 That's for distance, not heading, I presume.

Comment: @ispiro Just look in the header files. They could not really change it, unless they prevent existing compiled apps from running on an updated iOS version as it is a compiled constant of zero.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks. (What are these header files you speak of?)

Comment: The Xcode ObjC iOS header files... and I found where Xamarin bound that const `CoreLocation.CLLocationDistance.None` (unless the docs are wrong)

Comment: @SushiHangover I wouldn't even know how to start touching ObjC. So thanks a lot! (You can transform that into an answer if you want.)

Comment: @SushiHangover If you're referring to [the Microsoft docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/corelocation.cllocationdistance.filternone) - it's `kCLDistanceFilterNone`, ***not*** `kCLHeadingFilterNone` that is being used there.

Comment: @ispiro you're right, sorry. I see no binding for `kCLHeadingFilterNone` [in the (semi-)sources](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/main/src/corelocation.cs) :/